# Control should be fully postback though inside updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a update panel. Inside this i have several controls but the thing is i have a textbox for searching snagcode and i apply jquery autocomplete plugin to it.First time page load it works fine but not after this and that is obvious because it place inside update panel but i need to search snadcode one by one and i can't move the textbox outside updatepanel. What should i do ? Any suggestion from expert is highly expected. Here is my layout below...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepnlForSnagDefinationPATQA" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table width="100%" class="table table-stripe">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Snag Code:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSnagCode" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Search" ClientIDMode="Static"> </asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnFind" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="lnkbtnFind_Click"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Search</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        /// Some other controls here....
 </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtSnagCode" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If it should postback fully, why do you use an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` instead of a [`PostBackTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx)?

Comment: PostBackTrigger don't work for jquery autocomplete in second time after first time page loads though i set autopostback true to txtSnagCode

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your aspx page between

```
<script></script>
```

May be it can be helpful

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
       // Put your valueable code here [Between postbacks]
    });
```

Comment: is there any way inspite of besiding inside of update panel it don't share any functionality of update panel that means it is totally cut off part of update panel ?